# Putting button into the table column more elegantly

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Here is a SSCCE demonstrating how to put a `Button` into the `TableView` column. It works but with little unpleasant behavior. When the table rows are scrolled down **by mouse using the scroll bar**, the new rendered buttons are not shown immediately. They are shown only when the mouse is released and then moved. I think there is another more elegant way of displaying the button in the table column and when clicked doing some stuff related to the selected row. Any suggestions?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPaneBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class ButtonDemo extends Application {

    private TableView<Person> personTable = new TableView<>();
    private TableColumn<Person, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("name");
    private TableColumn<Person, Double> salaryCol = new TableColumn<>("salary");
    private TableColumn<Person, String> actionCol = new TableColumn<>("action");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            data.add(new Person("person_" + i, i * 100d));
        }

        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));
        salaryCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Double>("salary"));
        actionCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name")); // "name" here is for just to render the column

        Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>> printColumnCellFactory = //
                new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell call(final TableColumn param) {
                final TableCell cell = new TableCell() {

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setText(null);
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            final Button btnPrint = new Button("print name");
                            btnPrint.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                                @Override
                                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                                    param.getTableView().getSelectionModel().select(getIndex());
                                    Person item = personTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                                    if (item != null) {
                                        System.out.println(item.getName());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            setGraphic(btnPrint);
                            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        };
        actionCol.setCellFactory(printColumnCellFactory);

        personTable.setItems(data);
        personTable.getColumns().addAll(nameCol, salaryCol, actionCol);
        StackPane root = StackPaneBuilder.create().children(personTable).build();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public class Person {

        private String name;
        private Double salary;

        public Person(String name, Double salary) {
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Double getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of FX do u use? Can't reproduce your issue with FX 2.1 latest dev build - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html

Comment: Currently I am using javaFX 2.0.1. The buttons on the column are rendered immediately if the mouse's middle button is used for scrolling. Problem occurs when the scrolling is done by dragging the table's scroll bar. For the example code I posted, all buttons are eventually disappears if the scroll bar is dragged up and down simultaneously.

Comment: looks like a bug and your code is correct. Maybe you want to upgrade to 2.1dev? -- dragging scroll by mouse works there.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you create a button inside update(), isn't it inefficient to create a new button each time it paints? Here is what I am trying to do - create the button only in the constructor and reuse it in update() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851033/why-are-javafx2-2-buttons-in-my-table-view-code-not-visible

Comment: @Anil you may be right. I didn't test it. It was a demo to show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to version 2.1 resolved the problem.