# Get TableCell content for SQL query

Tags: java, javafx

I'm writing an SQL CRUD application and stuck on the delete button problem. I have a table with 4 columns and a delete button in the fifth. To make an SQL query I need to get info from these 4 columns. I can get a row number and a column name, how to get cell content on row/column intersection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the fifth column has a custom cell factory that puts the delete button in its custom TableCell, this delete button can own an action like:

```
btnDelete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        param.getTableView().getSelectionModel().select(getIndex());
        Person item = personTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (item != null) {
            // Logic of deleting current record here
            System.out.println(item.getName());
        }
    }
});
```

The full sscce, [Putting button into the table column more elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10044779/682495).